# What term is a hypernym for "story" and "article"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I need a single word that can be used to mean *article* (e.g. something printed in a magazine to inform readers or to argue something) and also *story* (i.e. some fictional short story printed in a literature publication).

Sometimes *story* is used to refer to a newspaper article, but readers will be confused if I simply use *story* as they might think I am excluding other types of non-fiction articles.

What term can I use to describe both kinds of writing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Often times, simply the term 'piece' as in 'piece of writing' is used.

i.e.

> I mainly do sports journalism, but I also write some fiction. I've had pieces published in The New Yorker, Sports Illustrated, and Esquire.

Comment: Strongly agreed.  This is the proper term.

Comment: A person would still need to qualify what "piece of writing" he or she did. "I've done several pieces for The New Yorker" could be about anything.

Answer (score 5):

If both are *contributions* to publications, you can use that.